# How to access on node modules package in cordova app

Tags: cordova, node-modules

i'm on project cordova app, and i'm using framework7 html for application on www directory, so i've install html-to-pdf on npm command , and when i tried to load this on javascript file (like require('html-to-pdf')) i've got error that require is undefined
So how to access on node_modules package if we want to use in javascript file ?
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

There are common ways, first is to use tool like Webpack. There are tons of contents about that in the web.

Second one is to use native JS modules, the question is whether you dependency supports that. Another thing is the browser support, modern browsers do support it, but older do not, you would need a polyfil for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this NPM module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-import-npm

> Import files from npm packages into your cordova www/ directory
> automatically, upon cordova prepare, cordova build or cordova run, and
> before anything else is processed.